# Unable join_cluster rabbitmq

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, erl

I have 2 nodes rabbitmq01 and rabbitmq2
when i try to join_cluster rabbitmq2 the following error appears
[image]

I also tried to check the version of erl
[image]

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

at first, on node `rabbitmq01` execute command:

```sh
sudo cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

then, on node `rabbitmq02`

```sh
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
sudo bash -c "echo rabbitmq01's cookie > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie"
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app
sudo rabbitmqctl reset  
sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@<rabbitmq01's hostname>
sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
```

if `join_cluster` failed, please check whether `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie` access pemission is 400 or 600